# @babel.localselector not called

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-babel

I have a problem using Flask Babel and python3.6.

My code is as following:

```
@babel.localeselector 
def get_locale():
    lang_supported = app.config.get('LANGUAGES', [])

    lang = request.accept_languages.best_match(lang_supported.keys())
    print('de', lang_supported)
    return lang
```

I do not get anything printed at the console. I do not know what I did wrong.

My App is initiated as following in the same file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config")
babel = Babel(app)
```

In my config file everything relevant to Babel is following:

```
LANGUAGES = {
    'en': 'English',
    'de': 'Deutsch' 
}

# BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES = '/path/to/flask/translations'
# BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'de'
# BABEL_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
```

While looking for some solutions, I also tried the commented lines.

I was able to use pybabel and create my `.pot`, `.po`, `.mo`,  files. And I created my Translation for 'de'

I do not find anything about, why my `print` statement is not executed.
When I manually create a `context_processor` and call my `get_locale()`, the print statement appears as expected.

Please let me know, if you need something more for debugging.

**Update:** code example calling the gettext

Inside of a view I called it for example like this:

```
from flask_babel import gettext as _
print(_('Hello'))
```

or

```
from flask_babel import gettext
print(gettext('Hello'))
```

and in Jinja2:

```
{{ _( 'Hello' ) }}
```

Comment: Can you show code were you require the translation?

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have added some code example.

Comment: Have you executed the ‘refresh’ function from Babel after the locale is changed? This should call the locale selector